# Can the verb "roll" be used for an object that does not move?

Tags: verbs

I would like to know which of "roll" and "rotate" is better in the following sentence I created.

> A printer has a roller inside to feed paper. The roller is supported by a shaft to a printer casing and **rolls/rotates** on the shaft.

I looked up "roll" in some dictionaries and found that it is usually used for a moving object, so I think "rotate" is better in the above sentence, but the name "roller" causes me to use "roll".

Comment: Are you saying that the roller is not moving?

Comment: Neither **supported to...a casing** nor **a shaft to a printer casing**  is idiomatic.  The roller is *mounted* (axially) on a shaft.  Does the entire shaft spin with the roller around it?  Or is the shaft fixed, with bearings between it and the roller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also use "rotate", but only because it avoids the repetition of "roll"

[Dictionary.com has](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/roll) "to revolve or turn over, once or repeatedly, as a wheel on an axis" as its tenth meaning of "roll". So it is correct to say "the roller rolls on the shaft"